# What does it mean it can't access this file?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

```
    user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
    [sudo] password for user: 
    user
    Sorry, try again.
    [sudo] password for user: 
    E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
    E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
     user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
    E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
    user@chrubuntu:~$
```

I'm trying to install Wine1.6 and i'm using the terminal. When I try to do it otherwise, it says that there are packages that are missing or uninstallable, what does that mean? Am I not able to download Wine?

Comment: That update manager can only run one instance at a time. When one is running, it locks the packaging manager and others have to wait for it to exit. If you ran Fedora, it actually keeps on checking unlike Ubuntu where it terminates off.

Comment: To understand why this happens, apt is essentially a database on top of dpkg, as a database it does not support simultaneous access and employs lockfiles as a form of [concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control). Usually this indicates that some other process has "claimed" the database (most commonly, ubuntu software center), but sometimes this can be caused by an improperly exited apt/synaptic process.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages probably mean that you have e.g. Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic running. Close them if you want to install from a terminal window.

Wine 1.6 is not (yet) installable in Ubuntu 14.04 due to missing dependencies. In the meantime you can install Wine 1.4.